# How to read multiple message status with imap faster

Tags: php, mysql, imap, status

I need to read the message status like : number of unread, read in each account. Each account is loop to get the  login data from mysql. When the login succeed, the number of read and unread is sent. The problem is it takes about 2 min to process all account (17) from mysql. How to make it faster. The ideal period is between 10-30 seconds. Could it possible?

Here is my code:

```
$sql_sImap=mysqli_query($con,"select * from LOGIN_DB order by imap_user asc");
while($rec_sImap=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_sImap)){

    $inbox=imap_open("{mail.xxx:143/novalidate-cert}INBOX", "$rec_sImap[imap_user]" , "$rec_sImap[imap_pw]");
    $num=imap_status($inbox,"{mail.xxx:143/novalidate-cert}INBOX", SA_ALL);
    $total=$num->messages;
    $unread=$num->unseen;
    $read=$total-$unread;


    echo "
    <tr>
        <td><a href=\"main.php?do=mail&action=view&sid=$rec_sImap[imap_sid]\">$rec_sImap[imap_user]</a></td>
        <td>".number_format($unread)."</td>
        <td>".number_format($read)."</td>
        <td>".number_format($total)."</td>
        <td><a href=\"main.php?do=mail&action=del_user&sid=$rec_sImap[imap_sid]\">del</a></td>
    </tr>
    ";
    $unread="";
    $read="";
    $total="";
}
```

As I mentioned above. These lines of code took me nearly 2 minutes to process. How could I make it faster?

Regards,

Comment: Do some timing to get the bottleneck. I don't think it's MySQL. Most time will be spend waiting for the IMAP answers, I'm sure.

Comment: Thank you VMai any solutions?

Comment: I would recommend to rewrite your code in three sections: 1) read the complete data from your db into an array (of rows), 2) get the IMAP data from those array into a second array, 3) write your HTML output. So you can easily measure the time spent in those parts.

Comment: Let me clear.  
$login_array=array("User A"=>"pw_A","User B"=>"pw_B");

$imap_array=array("msg_1"=>array("subj"=>"xxx","detail"=>"xxx"));

What then?

Answer (score 0):

Your code performs synchronous connection to each IMAP server in a series; this means that you have to wait for each connection to be established, including the TLS session handshake. That's a costly thing. Your best hope is switching to some IMAP library which supports asynchronous connection, so that you can open multiple TCP sockets at once, perform the SSL/TLS session handshake in parallel, and also run the necessary IMAP chat over multiple sockets at once. I don't think that the PHP's stock IMAP extension can do that.